# How can i give SECADM to instance owner in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

i'm using db2 9.7 on linux and i created a user "db2fee1i" to be a instance owner. I restored a database, but even being SYSADM i only can connect to database.
I need give DATAACCESS to another user, and appears...

("The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned: SQL0551N  "DB2FEE1I" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation "EXECUTE" on object "NULLID.SQLC2H23".  SQLSTATE=42501")

I  tryed everything but nothing solves my problem, now i found "SECADM" that can give me the "privileges to execute" into database, but i dont know how to do it.
Someone can help me?!

Answer (score 0):

Original database authorities and privileges are restored from the backup image, so by default your new instance owner ID does not have any special privileges apart from those inherited from `PUBLIC`.

Prior to restoring the database set the DB2 registry variable `db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON` and restart the instance. After the restore the authorization ID performing it will be granted `SECADM`, `DBADM`, `DATAACCESS`, and `ACCESSCTRL` authorities.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work too! The name of user is the same from old database instance...I made the process - db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON and instance has been restart but the message appears again. :(

Comment: What's the output of `select * from syscat.dbauth`?

Comment: db2 "select * from syscat.dbauth" ----- SQL0551N "DB2FEE1I" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation "EXECUTE" on object "NULLID.SQLC2H23". SQLSTATE=42501

Comment: What user ID created the database that you are restoring?

Comment: I restored the database logged with (db2fee1i) and i can't make SELECT or list schema or anything relationated with restored database...

Comment: So i need to be a SECADM to grant DBADM permission for my user or other users, this is what i understood with IBM documentation.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me ,
drop the db.

```
db2set DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON
```

then restore the DB.